# My NPM project won't get published

Tags: json, linux, node.js, npm

I'm pretty new to web development and so on, but I'm trying to develop a very small RESTful web app for a project; and I figured I'd try to do it the right way so I started following a few tutorials and so on. Long story short, I was following a tutorial called how-to-npm, when I ran into an issue when attempting to publish. I don't quite get the error message as the logic seems a bit backward to me. (It says it can't find the name in the registry, which [I think] is working as intended, because I'm still trying to publish it, but I think what might be happening is that it fails to publish my project, and then it checks if it's published or not later in the code, and finds it is indeed not published)

Please find the npm-debug.log data below - any help is appreciated. (Note: test.js is just an empty file)

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'publish' ]
2 info using npm@3.7.3
3 info using node@v5.7.0
4 verbose publish [ '.' ]
5 silly cache add args [ '.', null ]
6 verbose cache add spec .
7 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
7 silly cache add   raw: '.',
7 silly cache add   scope: null,
7 silly cache add   name: null,
7 silly cache add   rawSpec: '.',
7 silly cache add   spec: '/home/omar/Desktop/Projects/how-to-npm',
7 silly cache add   type: 'directory' }
8 verbose addLocalDirectory /home/omar/.npm/@linkclark/pkg/1.0.0/package.tgz not in flight; packing
9 verbose correctMkdir /home/omar/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
10 info lifecycle @linkclark/pkg@1.0.0~prepublish: @linkclark/pkg@1.0.0
11 silly lifecycle @linkclark/pkg@1.0.0~prepublish: no script for prepublish, continuing
12 verbose tar pack [ '/home/omar/.npm/@linkclark/pkg/1.0.0/package.tgz',
12 verbose tar pack   '/home/omar/Desktop/Projects/how-to-npm' ]
13 verbose tarball /home/omar/.npm/@linkclark/pkg/1.0.0/package.tgz
14 verbose folder /home/omar/Desktop/Projects/how-to-npm
15 verbose addLocalTarball adding from inside cache /home/omar/.npm/@linkclark/pkg/1.0.0/package.tgz
16 verbose correctMkdir /home/omar/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
17 silly cache afterAdd @linkclark/pkg@1.0.0
18 verbose afterAdd /home/omar/.npm/@linkclark/pkg/1.0.0/package/package.json not in flight; writing
19 verbose correctMkdir /home/omar/.npm correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
20 verbose afterAdd /home/omar/.npm/@linkclark/pkg/1.0.0/package/package.json written
21 silly publish { name: '@linkclark/pkg',
21 silly publish   version: '1.0.0',
21 silly publish   description: 'nu\'un',
21 silly publish   main: 'index.js',
21 silly publish   scripts: { test: 'node test.js' },
21 silly publish   repository:
21 silly publish    { type: 'git',
21 silly publish      url: 'git+https://github.com/OmarAYousry/how-to-npm.git' },
21 silly publish   keywords: [ 'how' ],
21 silly publish   author: { name: 'Omar' },
21 silly publish   license: 'ISC',
21 silly publish   dependencies: { '@linclark/pkg': '^1.0.2' },
21 silly publish   readme: 'This is the repo for my how-to-npm tutorial\n\nnothing else\n',
21 silly publish   readmeFilename: 'README.md',
21 silly publish   gitHead: '8ceb774a26300db413e522984b776246d8747372',
21 silly publish   bugs: { url: 'https://github.com/OmarAYousry/how-to-npm/issues' },
21 silly publish   homepage: 'https://github.com/OmarAYousry/how-to-npm#readme',
21 silly publish   _id: '@linkclark/pkg@1.0.0',
21 silly publish   _shasum: '47a5cba321a9be5e4e0a904623be0148619980e8',
21 silly publish   _from: '.' }
22 verbose getPublishConfig undefined
23 silly mapToRegistry name @linkclark/pkg
24 silly mapToRegistry scope (from package name) @linkclark
25 verbose mapToRegistry no registry URL found in name for scope @linkclark
26 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
27 silly mapToRegistry registry http://localhost:15443/
28 silly mapToRegistry uri http://localhost:15443/@linkclark%2fpkg
29 verbose publish registryBase http://localhost:15443/
30 silly publish uploading /home/omar/.npm/@linkclark/pkg/1.0.0/package.tgz
31 verbose request uri http://localhost:15443/@linkclark%2fpkg
32 verbose request sending authorization for write operation
33 info attempt registry request try #1 at 9:44:12 AM
34 verbose request id a61f260c4fe4949e
35 http request PUT http://localhost:15443/@linkclark%2fpkg
36 http 404 http://localhost:15443/@linkclark%2fpkg
37 verbose headers { 'content-type': 'application/json',
37 verbose headers   date: 'Sat, 27 Feb 2016 07:44:12 GMT',
37 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
37 verbose headers   'content-length': '19' }
38 verbose request invalidating /home/omar/.npm/localhost_15443/_40linkclark_252fpkg on PUT
39 error publish Failed PUT 404
40 verbose stack Error: missing : @linkclark/pkg
40 verbose stack     at makeError (/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:264:12)
40 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:252:14)
40 verbose stack     at Request._callback (/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:172:14)
40 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:199:22)
40 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
40 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:185:7)
40 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1036:10)
40 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
40 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:182:7)
40 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:963:12)
41 verbose statusCode 404
42 verbose pkgid @linkclark/pkg
43 verbose cwd /home/omar/Desktop/Projects/how-to-npm
44 error Linux 3.19.0-51-generic
45 error argv "/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/bin/node" "/home/omar/.nvm/versions/node/v5.7.0/bin/npm" "publish"
46 error node v5.7.0
47 error npm  v3.7.3
48 error code E404
49 error 404 missing : @linkclark/pkg
50 error 404
51 error 404 '@linkclark/pkg' is not in the npm registry.
52 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
53 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
54 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
55 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Why do you want to publish your app as a module?

Comment: Just following the tutorial to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend not to publish to NPM just for a sake of following the tutorial and using empty file.
The reason is that you will pollute it with not working software (as its just an empty file), and in addition, quoting NPM docs:

`once a package is published with a given name and version, that specific name and version combination can never be used again, even if it is removed with npm-unpublish`

Comment: Ah, I figured unpublishing it would mean completely removing it from the database of npm (name and all). I shall refrain then; thanks.